# Modifying the code_Deleting a line from the plot

Tags: r

For selecting the point several times (defining the intervals) I run the code
below, now I want to modify this code in a way that each time I choose a line, the system ask me whether I am happy with the result or not. If I say yes, the function keep that record otherwise delete it from the output and the plot. Also by clicking on a stop I could finish and leave the function and get the output.

```
func <- function(f){
  counter <- 1
  output <- list()
  while (TRUE) {    
    id.co1 <- identify(f$speed, f$dist,labels=row.names(f), n = 2, pos = TRUE,plot = TRUE)
    xy <- f[c(id.co1$ind[1],id.co1$ind[2]),]
    lines(xy, col="red", lwd=5)
    lm(dist~speed, xy)
    abline(coef(lm(dist~speed, xy)),col="blue") 
    x.co1 <- f$speed[id.co1$ind[1]:id.co1$ind[2]]
    y.co1 <- f$dist[id.co1$ind[1]:id.co1$ind[2]]
    m.co1 <- lm(y.co1 ~ x.co1)
    output[[counter]] <- list(xco =x.co1, yco=y.co1, lm =m.co1)
    counter <- counter+1
    continue <- readline("again? y/n: ")
#break the loop if the answer is 'n' or 'N'
    if (tolower(continue)=="n") break

  }
  output
}
speed<-cars$speed
dist<-cars$dist
level<-c(1:50)   
f<-data.frame(speed,dist,level)
plot(speed, dist, main="Milage vs. Car Weight", 
    xlab="Weight", ylab="Mileage", pch=18, col="blue")
text(speed, dist, row.names(f), cex=0.6, pos=4, col="red")
func(f)
```

I tried to modify this code in this way but It did not work since first I don't know how to define stop, as soon as clicking on a stop I want to finish/leave the algorithm and also the below code still keeps the selected points although I am not happy with them.

```
    func <- function(f){
  counter <- 1
  output <- list()
  while (TRUE) {    
    id.co1 <- identify(f$speed, f$dist,labels=row.names(f), n = 2, pos = TRUE,plot = TRUE)
    xy <- f[c(id.co1$ind[1],id.co1$ind[2]),]
    lines(xy, col="red", lwd=5)
    continue <- readline("are you happy with the line? y/n: ")
    if (tolower(continue)=="y") {  
    lm(dist~speed, xy)
    abline(coef(lm(dist~speed, xy)),col="blue") 
    x.co1 <- f$speed[id.co1$ind[1]:id.co1$ind[2]]
    y.co1 <- f$dist[id.co1$ind[1]:id.co1$ind[2]]
    m.co1 <- lm(y.co1 ~ x.co1)
    output[[counter]] <- list(xco =id.co1)
    counter <- counter+1
                               }
   continuee <- readline("Stop? y/n: ")
   if (tolower(continuee)=="y") break

              }
  output
}
speed<-cars$speed
dist<-cars$dist
level<-c(1:50)   
f<-data.frame(speed,dist,level)
plot(speed, dist, main="Milage vs. Car Weight", 
    xlab="Weight", ylab="Mileage", pch=18, col="blue")
text(speed, dist, row.names(f), cex=0.6, pos=4, col="red")
all1<-func(f)
```

Comment: Marco, please try this yourself first: you can see from your code how to use `readline` to prompt the user for input. I am sure you can find out how to ask "are you happy" and only if the result is "yes", store the output.

Comment: also, `base::plot` doesn't have something equivalent to an `undo` function: you'll have to redraw the plot and the accepted lines every time you add a line. But as you've got them stored in your output list, this isn't too problematic.

Comment: @ Janna Maas, thanks so much for the comment. I tried to fix the problem by myself but I could not. Please take a look at the second algorithm. It has some error and I donot know how to fix it.

Comment: you now have two instances where you require user input: once to ask whether the line is ok, and the second to ask whether the user is done: so you need two `readline` statements.

Comment: "removing" the line from the plot, which actually has to be re-drawing the plot and the lines you have up to then stored in `output`, is a second problem.

Comment: @ Janna Maas, I edited the second algorithm, I think it is working now. Your suggestion/advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ok! Now you need to put (re)drawing of the plot into your function- which means you could also make it more generic: `func <- function(x,y, ...)` and then `plot(x, y, ...)`, and use the `...` argument to pass your other parameters (`main`,`pch`, etc) on to your `plot` call.

Comment: @Janna Maas, could you please modify the second algorithm based on your suggestion. I didn't get your suggestion. Also sometimes when I run the second algorithm the two questions (are you happy with the line? and Stop?) appear at the same time, how can I fix this problem. The second question needs to appear as soon as I provide the answer to the first question.